# Windows 7 Password Expiration Notification

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, password

Under Windows 7, when the time comes for a password change, the 'password expiring' balloon comes up in the lower right area, but it's a bit small.
Does anyone know any tricks or tips to make this popup on the middle of the screen or directly at the logon screen (thinking back to XP)?

I found a way to script it [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/domain-password-expiration/95aceb4f-01ee-4212-8a3b-badd4a75ce6a) but I wasn't sure if there was an easier way through Group Policy and the like (running Server 2008 R2).

Thoughts?

Comment: There's a good powershell script knocking about which emails users to tell them how long until their password expires, if that's any help.

Answer (score 3):

i wrote a powershell script that runs every morning at 7:30. it emails users that have passwords that are expiring. ever since i put this in and amended the message to include instructions on updating the password on iphones and android phones, calls about passwords have dropped to 0.

it also emails us a list of all of the users that got a report. whoever is on call that week keeps an eye on the list to proactively call users that have 1 day left on friday.

http://pastebin.com/RpsSs7W3

Answer (score 0):

The powershell option is a nice minimal option.  I wrote and we are close to releasing a new version of [uManage](http://umanage.codeplex.com).  It's open source and includes a service that can run to check for expiring accounts and passwords.

Works a lot like the commercial packages but its free.  I would expect the next release in September.